# MapView.Polyline not working in react-native-web-maps

Tags: react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps, react-native-web

In my Android app it drawing the polyline but it not functioning in Web. I could not found any example even in that storybook. but In docs mentioned that it supports polyline.

**MyCode**

```
<MapView
    provider={this.props.provider}
    style={styles.map}
    initialRegion={this.state.region}
    onPress={e => this.onMapPress(e)}
    onLayout={()=>console.log('map on layout')}
    ref={(ref) => { this.mapRef = ref }}
    onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
>
    <MapView.Marker 
    coordinate={
                    {
                        latitude: 17.43745,
                        longitude: 78.48229
                        }
                }
    title={'pickup Location'}
    />

    <MapView.Marker 
    coordinate={
                    {
                        latitude: 17.4049696,
                        longitude: 78.4043356
                        }
                }
    title={'pickup Location'}
    pinColor="green"
    />
    <MapView.Polyline coordinates={this.dummyCoords} strokeWidth={2} strokeColor={'rgba(r,g,b,0.5)'} fillColor={'rgba(r,g,b,0.5)'}/>
</MapView>
```

Can anyone can share example, I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you please share a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your implementation?

Comment: Have you found solution for this problem ?

Comment: @Anoop at that time used `@mapbox/polyline` to draw the line. later changed it to `react-native-maps` but right now I didn't remember full implementation.